# Reset the position of an object's vertices

Tags: objects, vertices, transforms

I'm following the donut tutorial from Blender Guru and I accidentally moved a couple of vertices with the move tool. Is there any way to revert them to the original shape? I can't just undo it with ctrl+z because I did it some time ago without noticing.
[image]

[bottom view](https://imgur.com/a/gqIPyES)

[inside view](https://imgur.com/a/rUOcZqW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> doesn't work, you could select all and symmetrize on Y:

[image]

Choose the axis in the *Operator Box*:

[image]

Or select these vertices and delete:

[image]

Then select the opposite edges and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > *Grid Fill*:

[image]

Result:

[image]